# How to fork Bitcoin with ease

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain-fork, project-fork

I want to create a **fork** of Bitcoin which I can mine and have a wallet to send to another address to learn more about how Bitcoin works. Is there a very easy way to do this? Like can I just fork the github repo and change some lines and compile it all? Or is it a more intensive process?

A lot of the tutorials no longer work because they are very old.

Comment: You could simply use Testnet or Signet.

Comment: Why is this question marked as already answered. The OP wants to know how to develop a **new** and **different**   coin (also known as altcoin) but the question related if about how to develop an app based on bitcoin blockchain. Can the community please reopen this question as this question is not asking about the testnet but how to hard fork bitcoin.

Comment: @VarunW.: Hi Varun, the asker here wanted to have a chain to play around with to "learn more about how Bitcoin works". I think that can be achieved with a new Signet. Besides, questions about altcoin creation are not on-topic here.